# Django - How to make variable inside function to be available outside for data filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In Django, I want to filter data based on the selection made by the user from frontend drop down list. How can I make the return value within a function to be available outside the function? I'm using Django Rest Framework but I think same is true for Django in any case.

Here is my views.py

```
class ListAirlineYearFinancialData(generics.ListAPIView): # Serialized data
    serializer_class = FinancialDataSerializer

    def airline_dashboard(request):
        airline_list = Airline.objects.all() 
        year_list = Year.objects.all()

        if request.method == 'GET':
            identifier = request.GET.get('id', None)
            if identifier:
                airline_id = Airline.objects.filter(pk=identifier)
                return airline_id # How to reference this return value outside function to queryset below?
        return render(request, 'dashboard/company_page.html', {'airline_list': airline_list, 'year_list': year_list})

    queryset = FinancialData.objects.filter(airline_id=airline_id) # I get error airline_id is not defined
    queryset_filtered = queryset.filter(financial_year_id=1)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.queryset_filtered
```

Django is giving me an error that airline_id is not defined in queryset. How can I reference the value defined inside the function to be available outside and use that to filter data?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to move those two lines into the method.

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = FinancialData.objects.filter(airline_id=self.request.GET.get('id'))
    queryset_filtered = queryset.filter(financial_year_id=1)
    return queryset_filtered
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel but I think it will be an error that 'request' is not defined.

Comment: Sorry, should have been `self.request`.